# How do I make my grid adapt to the size of my container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I am trying to make my grid adapt to a predetermined size of my container dynamically, that is, even if the number of cells in my grid changes, it will continue with the same size.

```
const container = document.getElementById("container");

function makeRows(rows, cols) {
    container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
    container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);
    for (c = 0; c < (rows * cols); c++) {
        let cell = document.createElement("div");
        container.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item";
    };
};

makeRows(10, 10);
```

```
:root {
    --grid-cols: 1;
    --grid-rows: 1;
}

#container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 0;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
}

.grid-item {

    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>SketchPad</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>SketchPad</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="mode">Mode: Coloring</div>
        <div class="content">
            <div id="container"></div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <button class="blackButton" onclick="changeColor('black')">
                    Black
                </button>
                <button class="erasorButton" onclick="changeColor('white')">
                    Erasor
                </button>
                <button class="grayButton" onclick="changeColor('gray')">Gray</button>
                <button class="randomButton" onclick="changeColor('random')">
                    Random
                </button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Size of Board" value="16" onchange="changeSize(this.value)" />
                <button>Set Size</button>
            </div>
            <div class="error">Input must be between 2 and 100</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="App.js"></script>

</html>
```

I'm trying to make a SketchPad but when I change the number of cells in my grid it gets larger than the size of my container,the idea is that the size of the cells adapts automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re trying to set the **number of** columns. Instead, set the **width** of the columns and the **height** of the rows, and let `auto-fit` do the rest.

```js
const populateGrid = (id, x, y) => {
  const a = []
  for (let i = 0; i < x*y; i++) a.push('<div></div>')
  const e = document.getElementById(id)
  e.innerHTML = a.join('')
  e.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(auto-fit, calc(var(--size) / ${x}))`
  e.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(auto-fit, calc(var(--size) / ${y}))`
}

populateGrid('c1', 5, 5)
populateGrid('c2', 3, 6)
populateGrid('c3', 15, 10)
```

```css
:root {
  --size: 150px;
}

body {
  margin: 0.5em;
}

.container {
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  display: inline-grid;
  margin: 0.5em;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.container>*:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #662e9b;
}

.container>*:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f9c80e;
}
```

```html
<div id="c1" class="container"></div>
<div id="c2" class="container"></div>
<div id="c3" class="container"></div>
```